# How to split by recurrent identifier word in a file via Python

Tags: python, dictionary, split, pattern-matching, tuples

For the sake of minimalism, I simplify my case.

I have a file like this:

```
Name=[string] --------
Date=[string]
Target=[string]
Size=[string]
Name=[string] --------
Date=[string]
Size=[string]
Value=[string]
Name=[string] --------
Target=[string]
Date=[string]
Size=[string]
Value=[string]
```

I would like to store the record set(couple lines)that starts with `Name=[some string]` and continues until the next occurrence of `Name=[another string]` in a tuple/dictionary structure and enumerate them.
So, the desired output might look like this:

```
Enum,Name=[string],Date=[string],Target=[string],Size=[string], ---None---
Enum,Name=[string],Date=[string],   ---None---  ,Size=[string], Value=[string]
Enum,Name=[string],Date=[string],Target=[string],Size=[string], Value=[string]
```

I started working with line by line approach, yet it became computationally expensive. 
Is there any work around or functionality that may catch such recurring patterns and will they be useful and feasible for such formatting?

```
import re 
dict = {} 
with open("sockets_collection") as file: 
    i=0 for line in file: 
        match=re.findall(r'([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)',line) 
        dict[i]=(match[0]) 
        i=i+1 
print(dict)
```

This is a snippet for storing them as key value pairs. What I want to achieve is storing them as key value pairs but instead of having each enumerated, I want to have them grouped via key: `name`
P.S. if there any ambiguous parts please let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you have a piece of working code ("line by line approach"). If that is inefficient, then show us your current code and show us how slow it is (you measured that, right?). Then we might be able to give you ideas on how to speed it up.

Comment: this might be an approach split them on '/n' basis and then while traversing line by line split againg on basis of = and then use ordered dict with keys as Name,Date...and set the value of that key as 0 if we don't have a data for a particular key else simply add them...

Comment: `import re
dict = {}
with open("sockets_collection") as file:
 i=0
 for line in file:
  match=re.findall(r'([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)',line)
  dict[i]=(match[0])
  i=i+1
print(dict)`
Simply my approach storing every element and splitting them as key value pairs. Improvements required on one identifier key element which is name.

Comment: I added this to my question, as well.